# Why Mockito says that my stubbings are unnecessary

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock Spring's ConversionService so convert() method always returns the dto created by me, but Mockito says that my stubbings are unnecessary and mocked ConversionService returns null.

Here's the code:

**StudentServiceTests**

```java
package com.mdv.secondservice;

import com.mdv.secondservice.api.dto.ThirdServiceStudentDto;
import com.mdv.secondservice.api.proxy.ThirdServiceProxy;
import com.mdv.secondservice.db.model.Student;
import com.mdv.secondservice.db.repository.StudentRepository;
import com.mdv.secondservice.service.StudentService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class StudentServiceTests {
    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Mock
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Mock
    private ThirdServiceProxy thirdServiceProxy;

    @InjectMocks
    private StudentService studentService;

    private Student student;
    private ThirdServiceStudentDto thirdServiceStudentDto;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        final String middleName = "middleName";
        final String lastName = "lastName";
        student = Student.builder()
                .middleName(middleName)
                .lastName(lastName)
                .build();
        thirdServiceStudentDto = new ThirdServiceStudentDto(lastName);
    }

    @Test
    void createStudent_StudentWasCreated() {
        when(conversionService.convert(any(Student.class), same(ThirdServiceStudentDto.class)))
                .thenReturn(thirdServiceStudentDto);
        when(thirdServiceProxy.createStudent(any(ThirdServiceStudentDto.class))).thenReturn(student);
        when(studentService.createStudent(student)).thenReturn(student);

        Student returnedStudent = studentService.createStudent(student);

        assertThat(returnedStudent).isEqualTo(student);
    }
}
```

**StudentService**

```java
package com.mdv.secondservice.service;

import com.mdv.secondservice.api.dto.ThirdServiceStudentDto;
import com.mdv.secondservice.api.proxy.ThirdServiceProxy;
import com.mdv.secondservice.db.model.Student;
import com.mdv.secondservice.db.repository.StudentRepository;
import feign.FeignException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentService {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;
    private final ConversionService conversionService;
    private final ThirdServiceProxy thirdServiceProxy;

    public Student createStudent(Student student) throws FeignException.InternalServerError {
        ThirdServiceStudentDto thirdServiceStudentDto =
                conversionService.convert(student, ThirdServiceStudentDto.class);
        Student createdStudent = thirdServiceProxy.createStudent(thirdServiceStudentDto);

        createdStudent.setMiddleName(student.getMiddleName());
        studentRepository.save(createdStudent);

        return createdStudent;
    }
}
```

It seems like I messed up with matchers in the first **when** call. I know I didn't mock StudentRepository, I will fix that later. The problem is that *conversionService.convert(...)* returns null when called in *StudentService.createStudent* method.

UPD (added Mockito error):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mdv.secondservice.service.StudentService.createStudent(StudentService.java:26)
    at com.mdv.secondservice.StudentServiceTests.createStudent_StudentWasCreated(StudentServiceTests.java:59)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.mdv.secondservice.StudentServiceTests.createStudent_StudentWasCreated(StudentServiceTests.java:56)
  2. -> at com.mdv.secondservice.StudentServiceTests.createStudent_StudentWasCreated(StudentServiceTests.java:58)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:181)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:255)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:271)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:271)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:270)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:143)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: Error message from Mockito please?

Comment: Does it work with `.convert(any(), any()))`  ? (Only for locating the problem) And why you try to mock this:    `        `when(studentService.createStudent(student)).thenReturn(student);`? This is your service you want test or?

Comment: @rogerdpack Just added.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 No, it doesn't. Got the same NRE pointing to         `createdStudent.setMiddleName(student.getMiddleName())` (StudentService.create).
And yes, you are right, that mock is unnecessary. But that's not the problem, Mockito is pointing to the other two mocks above. It seems like Mockito is ignoring those two..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mock everything, you dont need the spring boot context.
You can delete the `@SpringBootTest`.
And your example should run.

Otherwise you can replace `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`  with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I suppose the problem was that Spring context contained ConversionService which hadn't been mocked.